# Polymorphic Argument of a overridden method

Tags: java, arguments, overriding, polymorphism

We have a case where we need build a `Resource` which can be one of two types: `Logical` or `Physical`. With each resource subtype, we have a `Configuration` attached which can be a `LogicalConfiguration` and a `PhysicalConfiguration`.

This is done because the configuration objects are editable and need to be versioned. Such as a resource can have two configuration versions: active and draft. A method is provided in `Resource` to Add a configuration `addConfiguration(Configuration config)`

Now, we are facing a issue, `LogicalConfiguration` can be wrongly passed to `addConfiguration` method for a `PhysicalResource`.

```
Resource resource = new PhysicalResource()
Configuration config = new LogicalResourceConfiguration();
physicalResource.addConfiguration(config)
```

This invocation will succeed and a wrong configuration will get added. Following ways can be used to avoid this.

1. We do the `instanceOf` check or define a member `Type`, but this will kill polymorphism.
2. We create two methods `addLogicalConfiguration`/`addPhysicalConfiguration` one of them fails at Runtime.

What will be the most suitable way to approach this problem ? Or is there a specific pattern to address these kind of issues?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a generic type parameter to the Resource class:

```
class Resource<T extends Configuration> {
    public void addConfiguration(T config) {}
}
```

Then, you can have:

```
class PhysicalResource extends Resource<PhysicalConfiguration> {...}

class LogicalResource extends Resource<LogicalConfiguration> {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

This structure should fulfill your expectations, by giving a *compilation* error when an attempting to add an incorrect `Configuration` type to a `Resource`:

```
abstract class Configuration  {
}
   class LogicalConfiguration extends Configuration  {
   }
   class PhysicalConfiguration extends Configuration  {
   }
abstract class Resource<C extends Configuration>  {
   private C config;
   public void addConfiguration(C config)  {
      this.config = config;
   }
   public C getConfig()  {
      return  config;
   }
}
   class LogicalResource extends Resource<LogicalConfiguration>  {
   }
   class PhysicalResource extends Resource<PhysicalConfiguration>  {
   }
```

Use it exactly as you do in your example:

```
Resource resource = new PhysicalResource()
Configuration config = new LogicalResourceConfiguration();

//COMPILATION ERROR:
physicalResource.addConfiguration(config);
```

Comment: Thanks for the generic solution, will go ahead with this, but was more keen to find some solution in some pattern or instanceOf to be suggested as a good alternative in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Put the classes into their own package and make `addConfiguration` in `Resource` protected.

That way, anyone using your package will discover the error at code writing time.